# Actual Folder Size?

Tags: hard-drive, macos

I have a TM back up from a retired drive. The folder info screen looks like this.

[image]

The drive is 3TB and there's still 900GB free, so the 4.75TB reported size is not correct. Is there a simple way to find out how big this folder actually is? I need to archive it someplace and want to know how much space it actually takes up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to get size information from the command line, especially when I have an administrator account on the computer and I'm logged in with that user.

Open a terminal (either cmd-spacebar/Spotlight and then type "terminal" or through Applications->Utilities).

Type:
    sudo du -sh /Volumes/Feynman 3.0 and hit enter

You will be prompted for your admin password, and then du will calculate the size of the folders/files on the disk.

You can also then add to the path (or add "/*" on the end of "/Volumes/Feynman 3.0") to get the sizes of the subfolders to aid in further troubleshooting.